# How to get multiselect dropdown in AgGrid using Angular

Tags: angular, dropdown, ag-grid-angular

We have AgGrid and we need a multiselect dropdown for one of the column, and we are using Angular 7.

I am able to find multiselect dropdown but not for agGrid Cell.

Please help.

I a able to produce agGrid, tried using below link but unable to get.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-add-combobox-in-aggrid-or-edit-grid-coloumn-with-combobox

Expected : multi select dropdown in agGrid cell

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, please mark me in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working with Ag-grid for months and I can tell you it is very difficult to put something customized onto Aggrid cells.

Firstly, you can you use frameworkComponents parameter of GridOptions belonging to the related Ag-grid table.

**Usage description:**
You have a independent component that providing you to select multiple item in a dropdown element. Let's name this component as **MultiSelectComponent**

Firstly, import GridOptons from any type of Ag-grid modules. I am using Enterprise.

```
import { GridOptions, ... } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
import { MultiSelectComponent} from './multi-select-component';
```

And inside Component class, declare details.

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
...
columnDefs: any;
...
gridOptions: GridOptions;
this.gridOptions = {
 frameworkComponents: {
  cellCustomComponent: MultiSelectComponent
 }
}
```

Here we define columns and their options we want. First column definition is containing our custom component in it. According to my  **Custom component can shown on Ag-grid in two ways:**

1) It can be shown as the **grid is ready.** It is used with `cellRenderer`.

2) It can be displayed right **after cell is clicked** to edit. For this, you must declare the column to be **editable as true**. Also it is used with `cellEditor` and `cellEditorParams`.

Now We are using 1st option. I mean, `cellRenderer` one. I recommend you the same way too.

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Names', field: 'names',
    cellRenderer: 'cellDatePicker', pinned: 'left',
  },
  // other columns definitions here
]
```

Now it is almost ready to display our own custom component right inside the cells under 'Names' column we just defined above. If our custom component is a datepicker, then it is shown as that datepicker. If it is an emoji selector picker, then it is as that is. (For example, [click the link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/) for cellEditor and cellRenderer)

*My own custom component, datepicker:*

[image: My own custom component, datepicker]

[Click resource on Aggrid site](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/)

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, you kindly can mark it as the answer @akshay-krishna.

Answer (score 2):

I'll make it simple. It took me 2 days to make one with plain javascript. You can adjust it to your Angular needs.

Include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/themes/frt/vendors/custom/bootstrap-multiselect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/themes/frt/vendors/custom/bootstrap-multiselect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

Style

```
<style> #commentSelection { width: 100%; } .input-widget-popup { width: 250px; height: 100px; } table { width: 100%; height: 100%; } td, th { text-align: center; padding: 8px; } </style>
```

Customize

```
var selectedComments = [];

class CommentCellRenderer {
    init(params) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('span');
        if (params.value !== "" && params.value !== undefined && params.value !== null) {
            this.eGui.innerHTML = params.value;
        }
    }

    getGui() {
        return this.eGui;
    }
}

class CommentPopupCellEditor {
    init(params) {
        this.container = document.createElement('div');
        this.container.setAttribute('class', 'input-widget-popup');
        this._createTable(params);
        this.params = params;

        var commentUids = '';
        var commentNames = '';
        var rowSelectedComments = selectedComments.filter(comment => comment.rowId === params.node.id);
        for (var i = 0; i < rowSelectedComments.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                commentUids += ',';
                commentNames += ',';
            }
            commentUids += rowSelectedComments[i].uid;
            commentNames += rowSelectedComments[i].name;
        }
        this.selectComment(commentUids, commentNames);
    }

    selectComment(commentUids, commentNames) {
        this.commentList = commentNames;

        var rowNode = gridOptions.api.getRowNode(this.params.node.id);
        rowNode.setDataValue('comment_uid', commentUids);
        rowNode.setDataValue('comment_name', commentNames);
        setTimeout(() => {
            App.autoSizeAll(gridOptions);
        }, 1000);
    }

    getGui() {
        return this.container;
    }

    afterGuiAttached() {
        var that = this;
        $('#commentSelection').multiselect({
            buttonWidth: '100%',
            onChange: function(element, checked) {
                var x = element[0];
                var commentUid = $(x).val().toString();
                var commentName = $(x).text().toString();

                if (checked) {
                    var index = selectedComments.filter(comment => comment.rowId === that.params.node.id).map(function(e) { return e.uid; }).indexOf(commentUid);
                    if (index === -1) {
                        selectedComments.push({
                            rowId: that.params.node.id,
                            uid: commentUid,
                            name: commentName
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    selectedComments = selectedComments.filter(comment => comment.rowId !== that.params.node.id || comment.uid !== commentUid);
                }

                var commentUids = '';
                var commentNames = '';
                var rowSelectedComments = selectedComments.filter(comment => comment.rowId === that.params.node.id);
                for (var i = 0; i < rowSelectedComments.length; i++) {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        commentUids += ',';
                        commentNames += ',';
                    }
                    commentUids += rowSelectedComments[i].uid;
                    commentNames += rowSelectedComments[i].name;
                }
                that.selectComment(commentUids, commentNames);
            }
        });
        this.container.focus();
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.commentList;
    }

    isPopup() {
        return true;
    }

    _createTable(params) {
        this.container.innerHTML = `
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo COMMENTS; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="commentSelection" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
`;
        this.commentDropdown = this.container.querySelector('#commentSelection');
        for (let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.setAttribute('value', comments[i].uid.toString());
            var index = selectedComments.filter(comment => comment.rowId === params.node.id).map(function(e) { return e.uid; }).indexOf(comments[i].uid);
            if (index !== -1) {
                option.selected = true;
            }
            option.innerText = comments[i].name;
            this.commentDropdown.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}
```

Reference

```
{headerName: '', field: 'comment_name', editable: true, cellEditor: 'commentPopupCellEditor', cellRenderer: 'commentCellRenderer'},
```

Option

```
components: {
    commentCellRenderer: CommentCellRenderer,
    commentPopupCellEditor: CommentPopupCellEditor,
},
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CRCn.png)

Comment: hey, would you please include by any chance the versions you are using for bootstrap and jquery? I am trying to use your code, it seems to work but the dropdown doesn't get rendered properly, if you could please clarify the include part it would be fantastic :)  at the moment you only have bootstrap-multiselect twice, while I think you have boostrap js and css, jquery js and css, boostrap-multiselect js and css. many thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Chosen Version 1.8.7, Typeahead Version 0.11.1, Bootstrap Multiselect Version 2.0, jQuery UI Version v1.12.1